# migrate.py: Unknown command: 'migrate'

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.3.7 (Python 2.7) and I want to use the `migrate` command with `manage.py`.
But I get *Unknown command*:

```
[fuiba@web300 app]$ python2.7 manage.py migrate --settings=settings --fake
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I added South to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py, and before run migrate I exported the settings and I run `syncdb`:

```
[fuiba@web300 app]$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
[fuiba@web300 app]$ python2.7 manage.py syncdb --settings=settings
```

Also in Python shell I get **No module named migrate**:

```
[fuiba@web300 app]$ python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 16 2013, 20:16:09) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named migrate
>>>
```

Probably is a problem with Python because when I run this command to get which version I am running I get `''` instead of path:

```
[fuiba@web300 app]$ which python
alias python=''
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is **absolutely no good reason** to be using Django 1.3, which is four years old. You should upgrade to the current version, 1.6. (But even with the correct version and South properly installed, you wouldn't be able to import "migrate" in the shell; that's not how management commands work.)

Comment: Did you run manage.py help as suggested by the error message

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman I will update Django to last version.

Comment: You're having multiple settings file ? (One for debug , one for production etc) if so then you're not setting the settings argument right.